# Numpy extracting values from 1d array using 2d array of indices

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I start with an m x n matrix called `values`. I then use np.argpartition to get the k minimum indices for each of the m rows, returned in a new m x k matrix called `min_indices`. It might be wrong, but this is what I did:
`min_indices = np.argpartition(values, k, axis=1)[:, :k]`.
Next, I have an n x 1 matrix, called `labelsArray`. The each index in `min_indices` corresponds to an index into this array of labels. What I'd like to be able to do is to convert (either in place or by returning a new matrix) each index in `min_indices` to its corresponding label (i.e. given another m x k matrix `result` `result[m][k] = labelsArray[min_indices[m][k]]` for all m and k). I could accomplish this programmatically, but is there an efficient and concise way to perform this transformation in numpy?

values look like: [[0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, ...n], [0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.6, ...n], ....m]

so there are m float values in each row, and there are n total rows. So basically each test example(represented by row) has distance given by column to each training sample.

labelsArray look like: [car, bird, fly, poster, ...n]

given k = 2, result should look like: [[fly, poster], [car, bird], [bird, poster], ...n]

So, min_indices basically should have indices of k-nearest neighbors for each test example. Then, I would like to use those indices to get the labels of each of those neighbors from labelsArray for each test example. Explained by example above.

Comment: Post your code instead of describing it.

Comment: Or post a minimal example of your `values`, `labelsArray` and the desired `rersult`.

Comment: Thanks guys, just added more example and description.